# How do I remove the "Enabling {plugin} {version}" message from the logger?

Tags: java, logging, bukkit

Is there a way to remove these messages from Bukkit, in order to add custom ones?

> [{plugin}] Loading {plugin} {version}
>   [{plugin}] Enabling {plugin} {version}

I want to replace the 1st and the 2nd line of this image with the 3rd to 5th ones.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can filter `System.out` for your message if you really want to:

```
PrintStream old = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(old) {
    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        if (s != null && s.matches(
            ".*?\\[NoOpenHopper]\\s(Loading|Enabling)\\sNoOpenHopper.+" regex))
            super.print("NoOpenHopper has been enabled!");
        super.print(s);
    }
});
```

You could use this in the constructor of your plugin to make sure that this procedure is carried out before your plugin is enabled, therefore the logging messages are effectively overridden.

Please make sure you are aware of the caveats first:

1. You must really trust your filtering skills. If you're not sure if it catches anything else, don't do it. (If you don't know what this does, don't steal it, you will actually break a lot with this.)
2. This creates a new `PrintStream` object. Instead of filtering with a wrapping object, you may as well use reflection (Look into `Proxy` and `unreflect`) for this to be more effective without dumping garbage into the heap. Though, AWT does this, Sun does this, and even CraftBukkit does this, so not much of a worry.
3. This is an atomic erasure of the logging messages, and you cannot revert unless you keep a reference of `old` and therefore reset `System.setOut` afterwards (which you really should or your server owner would really hate you).

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** You would need to change the server source.

Those messages are very useful. They help the user to quickly locate errors and many other things.

Just because they are, [you should keep the console clean](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#onEnable.28.29_and_onDisable.28.29).

> There is no reason to print a message such as "{$PluginName} has been enabled!" as bukkit will do this automatically.